# Cluster option does not exist in vis.js timeline

Tags: angular, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

The [configuration option](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options) for `cluster` does not seem to work in vis.js timeline

Here is how I am setting things up with TypeScript:

```
  const options = {
    height: '400px',
    zoomMin: 5000,
    stack: true,
    cluster: {
      showStipes: true,
      maxItems: 2,
    },
    template: (item, element, data) => {
      return this.timelineItemService.toHTMLElement(
        this.timelineItemComponents.filter((x) => x.instance.id === item.id)[0]);
    }
  };

  const groups = [
      { id: 'Item', content: 'Item' },
      { id: 'Event', content: 'Event' },
  ];

  this.contentElement.subscribe((domEl) => {
    this.timeline = new vis.Timeline(domEl, items, groups, options);
  ... other code omitted ...
```

In the debug console I am getting this error:

```
Unknown option detected: "cluster" in
options = {
  cluster
}

Perhaps it was misplaced?

Matching option found at: options = {
  configure: {
    filter
  }
}
```

Am I setting it up incorrectly or is there an issue with that option? Everything else I have done is rendering and working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install and use`vis-timeline` along with all the required dependencies if you were originally only using `vis`

vis.js has some but not all the functionality that vis-timeline.js has